# EF not grabbing an object when its navigation property is null

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

My issue is - if a navigation property is 'null' in the DB, my query won't return the main object I'm querying for.

For clarity, my issue is NOT the navigation property inside .Include() being returned null.  My issue is the property IS expected to be null, and when it is, Market is not being returned.

Here's an example of what I mean:

My code:

```
            markets = await _context.Markets
                .Include(x => x.Agency)
                .Include(x => x.Location)?.ThenInclude(x => x.State)?
                .Include(x => x.Location).ThenInclude(x => x.Country)
                .Where(x => x.Deleted == false
                && x.Agency.Deleted == false).ToListAsync();
```

I have some Markets, who have a navigation property `Location`, which in turn has a navigation property `State`.  For some `Location`, `State` is null.  The foreign key to `State` defined in the `Location` model is a `long?`.

However, for some reason, my Markets with null States' aren't being returned in the resulting list, entities which have all those fields included in the .Include() statements, and are not null, are being returned.

I originally had my code without the `?` after my includes... like:

`.Include(x => x.Location).ThenInclude(x => x.State)` and that did not work.  I added the nullable thinking it may help, though it did not.

Does anyone have any tips here?  When running this statement, I get this exception:
`.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.`
However, the exception does not break the flow, and I get objects returned that don't have a null `State`.

Any and all tips would be appreciated!

EDIT:

It's important to note, the code works perfectly fine when all my navigation properties are NOT null.  It's when State is null (the only nullable navigation property) that this issue shows up.

Models:

```
public class Market
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long MarketId { get; set; }
        
        [ForeignKey("Location")]
        public long HeadquartersId { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
}

public class Location
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long LocationId { get; set; }
        
        [ForeignKey("State")]
        public long? StateId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Country")]
        public long CountryId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual State State { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try this `.Include("Location").Include("Location.State")`?

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty Interesting idea, I gave it a shot and unfortunately it did not work :(

Comment: Can you show the model and their configuration?

Comment: @ESG Sure, I've just included my models in an edit on the original post - hopefully it may shed some light on what's going wrong here.

Comment: The required might be an issue since the framework might assume that those relationships are not optional. Have you tried making them optional va `OnModelCreating` in the DbContext?

Comment: @ESG it unfortunately does need to stay required, because it's used in form validation for Blazor, and frustratingly, Blazor uses the same annotations EF does.  Lots of conflicts like this one as a result. Your suggestion, however, DID work.  I think I'm just going to need to do another query to grab Markets' when Country is a certain value, because it tells me if State will be null.  Not as efficient, but maybe necessary....

Comment: @ESG And whoever else may find this later - this is one of many examples of why, when using Blazor, I think it may be a better idea to have separate models for the frontend & backend.  I've gone too deep to back out now, but it causes many frustrating conflicts with [Required] tags, and much more.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit of a longshot, but see if you can manually configure the relationships in your DBContext's `OnModelCreating`.

Example:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<Market>(a =>
    {
        a.HasOne(e => e.Location).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.HeadquartersId).IsRequired(false);                
    });

    builder.Entity<Location>(a =>
    {
        a.HasOne(e => e.State).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.StateId).IsRequired(false);                
        a.HasOne(e => e.Country).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.CountryId).IsRequired(false);                
    });

}
```

Comment: Just curious...Do you have a good source for explaining the .HasOne .WithMany...and just other Fluent options.

Comment: This solution actually didn't work, however removing [Required] on my Location navigation property (rather than setting the ForeignKey to .IsRequired(false)) did work.  In my situation though, I had to keep [Required], so I had to workaround in my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the issue was the [Required] annotation on my State navigation property in my Location model.

Unfortunately, this is one of many examples of conflicts between Entity Framework and Blazor using the same data annotations.

In my example, State is required because it's needed for form validation in Blazor.  However, in my database, StateId is actually a nullable foreign key, because it's not necessarily required in the backend.

I've come up with two workarounds, feel free to add addtional ones if you know of a better solution.

1. Create separate frontend models for Blazor, and backend models for EF. I know, ugly duplicate code. However, This can keep concerns separated, and avoid a mess of "required here, but not here" type issues.
2. In my situation, I could also have a separate query, checking my Country first. if Country is a certain value, I won't .Include(x => x.State). This is more specific, but may be necessary for some in similar situations where there is already a codebase that cannot be changed so much.

Comment: You really should be keeping your DTOs and your view models separate anyway. They are two entirely different domains. That's why libs like Automapper exist to convert between the two.